# Does ESPN's API return images

Tags: json, api, rest, espn

Does the ESPN API return links to player images for any sport? I need to show the player images along with the other data I am successfully able to retrieve. If not is there another recommended way to retrieve these images?

Comment: You might want to tag this question with stuff like "web services," "REST," "JSON," etc.

Comment: thanks for helping out a newbie. done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had no idea ESPN had an API. That's awesome.

From the [documentation](http://developer.espn.com/docs/athletes#returned-data), it looks like you can find images through the *headshots* property in the response (if available):

```
headshots   Collection of athlete headshots as specified below, each containing href, width, and height attributes. Soccer, recruiting, and WNBA not currently supported. Note: clients apps must be responsible for handling missing headshots as not every athlete has one.               
full 600x436 athlete headshot               
xlarge 350x254 athlete headshot             
large 65x90 athlete headshot                
medium 43x60 athlete headshot               
small 34x48 athlete headshot                
xsmall 28x38 athlete headshot               
fantasy 200x145 athlete headshot
```

There is also a Video [API](http://developer.espn.com/docs/video#overview), but it doesn't look like it's keyed on athlete.